# Storing simple key value pairs with Flask Cache and memcached

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-cache

How can I store simple key value pairs with Flask Cache? Something like this:

```
cache.set('key', 'some value')
cache.get('key')
```

Now I only store a function's return value using the cache.cached() decorator. That method seams to work, but I don't know how to manually clear that function's cache before it timeouts on it's own.

Idealy, I would like to be able to set cache values based on a key, like in the example. Is that possible using memcached as the backend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flask has an in-built method for Caching where you can utilize `Memcache` to store Cache as key-value pairs:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import MemcachedCache
cache = MemcachedCache(['127.0.0.1:11211'])

def get_my_item():
    rv = cache.get('my-item')
    if rv is None:
        rv = calculate_value()
        cache.set('my-item', rv, timeout=5 * 60)
    return rv
```

You can find more about it on [Flask Cache](http://web.archive.org/web/20170717163232/http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/caching/)

Comment: The link was broken, so I edited it to point to the Web Archive version. A [modern version of that page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/caching/) instead points to the [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension.